# REGEX - parsing variables after file extension

Tags: regex

I'm trying to automatically embed image links in wordpress and this is where im stuck at - right now

The problem is that when i post facebook image links - it comes with queries after the .jpg - so the current plugin emebeds the image till that point - i want it to cover the entire query area as well

IMG URL

> `https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/39227322_318658432236051_8750467176600698880_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&oh=3c0b91f37a0809c9dace85429151986a&oe=5BC5EC9F`

REGEX (in wordpress plugin) that affects this url

```
$content  =
preg_replace('#((?!"|\')http(s?)://([^\s]*)\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)(?!"|\'))#',
'<img class="embedded-image-link" src="$1">', $content);
```

Output - as you can see it stops right after .jpg

```
<img data-expand="600" 
data-src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/39227322_318658432236051_
8750467176600698880_n.jpg">?_nc_cat=0&amp;_nc_ad=z-m&amp;_nc_cid=0&amp;oh=3c0b91f3
7a0809c9dace85429151986a&amp;oe=5BC5EC9F
```

I want it to go way after .jpg - untill it hits the end or else the image wont load.

Comment: Try `'~(?<!["\'])https?://[^\'"\s<]*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)(?:\?[^\'"\s<]*)?~'` and replace with `'<img class="embedded-image-link" src="$0">'`. See https://regex101.com/r/ptDf3C/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
This got my way closer!!!

Comment: So, shall I post that one? How close is that? What is your required output? Try also https://regex101.com/r/ptDf3C/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this totally helped my problem and i didnt know about that site regex101 - such a life saver!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~<a\s+[^>]*>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*F)|https?://[^'"\s<]*\.(?:jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)(?:\?[^'"\s<]*)?~si'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptDf3C/3)

**Details**

- `<a\s+[^>]*>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches an `a` tag and skips it (due to `(*SKIP)(*F)`) (you may add any other tag here after `|`, e.g. `(?:<img[^>]*>|<a\s+[^>]*>.*?</a>)(*SKIP)(*F)`)
- `|` - or
- `https?://` - a `http://` or `https://` substring
- `[^'"\s<]*` - 0+ chars other than `'`, `"`, whitespace and `<`
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)` - any of the alternatives: `jpg`, `jpeg`, `gif`, `png`, `bmp`
- `(?:\?[^'"\s<]*)?` - an optional sequence of a `?` char followed with any 0 or more chars other than `'`, `"`, whitespace and `<`.